# Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65" Iphone6 Simulator

Tags: xcode, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

I am trying to run the Amazon app on an iPhone 6 simulator using Xcode.

The app is getting installed in the iPhone Simulator, but not able to interact with its elements.

Appium version - 1.7.2
Xcode Version 9.2
Platform Mac- 10.12.6
Downloaded the app - i.e. xxx.app.ipa

Logs:

> [Xcode] 2018-02-13 21:23:08.009 xcodebuild[9868:75242] Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Cannot launch simulated executable: no file found at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot launch simulated executable: no file found at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app} [Xcode] 2018-02-13 21:23:08.009 xcodebuild[9868:75242]
>
> Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted} [Xcode] [Xcode] 2018-02-13 21:23:08.010 xcodebuild[9868:75259] Connection peer refused channel request for "dtxproxy:XCTestManager_IDEInterface:XCTestManager_DaemonConnectionInterface"; channel canceled
>
> [Xcode] ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED ** [Xcode] [Xcode] 2018-02-13 21:23:08.011 xcodebuild[9868:75318] Error saving test log:
>
> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Logs/Test/921A213D-B7E4-4994-9443-F73DDE5FBD4D.xcactivitylog, NSLocalizedDescription=No such file or directory} | User info: { [Xcode] NSFilePath = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Logs/Test/921A213D-B7E4-4994-9443-F73DDE5FBD4D.xcactivitylog"; [Xcode] NSLocalizedDescription = "No such file or directory"; [Xcode] } [Xcode]
>
> [XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null' [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1518585788035 (21:23:08 GMT-0800 (PST)) [XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". [XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent, then retrying [XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes [XCUITest] Removing WDA application from device [XCUITest] Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:375:13) at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40) at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke as _invoke at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) as next at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37) at Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:375:13) at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40) at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke as _invoke at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) as next at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37) at [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use clearSystemFiles capability to turn on. [XCUITest] Killing running processes 'xcodebuild.B720A212-489B-4A48-BBDB-7119C9763406, B720A212-489B-4A48-BBDB-7119C9763406.*XCTRunner' for the device B720A212-489B-4A48-BBDB-7119C9763406... [XCUITest] 'pgrep -nif xcodebuild.*B720A212-489B-4A48-BBDB-7119C9763406' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1 [XCUITest] 'pgrep -nif B720A212-489B-4A48-BBDB-7119C9763406.XCTRunner' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1 [XCUITest] Deleting simulator created for this run (udid: 'B720A212-489B-4A48-BBDB-7119C9763406') [iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture

Answer (score 0):

It's saying it can't find the WebDriver app. Can you confirm its existence in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/`?

If it doesn't exist, there is something wrong with your Appium install so I'd recommend reinstalling `npm uninstall -g appium` and `npm install -g appium`. Probably safe to do that anyway.

Also make sure you restart your device and uninstalling any existing WebDriver app on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Error clear shows --  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app}

Webdriver agent need to be successfully running on device 
Try to configure Webdriver agent and Developer ID ::

1. Open the existing the WebDriver Agent (double click on WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj)
2. On top of Xcode you File > New> File , then you will an pop up something like this
3. Select OSX->.Other-> Select Configuration settings file.
4. Paste the following things in newly created file.

DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = xxxxxxxxx

CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer

Development team is Team ID which your developer should be able to provide . Dont change the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY.

In device.propoerties file add this

xcodeConfigFile=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Config.xcconfig

In ConfigCapa.java file add this

capabilities.setCapability(“xcodeConfigFile”,emulatorProp.getProperty(“xcodeConfigFile”));

Open terminal go to

$ cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/

$ mkdir -p Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle

sh ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh –d

Go to terminal type

xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination ‘id=DeviceID’ test Last line on build output above command should be Listening on USB. Then you are all set!

brew install libimobiledevice –HEAD

To run appium type appium &

To find version type appium — v